# Why $S$ cannot be homeomorphic to the $1$-sphere of $\ell^2$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces

Consider the $\ell^2$ complex Hilbert space.

Let $m\in \mathbb{N}^*$ be a fixed number, and set 
$$
S=\left\{ x=(x_n)_n\subset \ell^2\ :\ \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{|x_n|^2}{n^2}=1\right\}.$$

> I want to show that $S$ is not homeomorphic to 
>   $$
> S(0,1)=\left\{ x=(x_n)_n\subset \ell^2\ :\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^2=1\right\}.$$

Comment: What do you mean by $(x_n)_n$?

Comment: @AmirSagiv $(x_n)_n$ is a standard notation to mean the sequence $n\mapsto x_n$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sure, now I get it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$S$ contains the ellipsoid $\{x\in \mathbb C^m: \sum \frac{|x_n|^2}{n^2}=1\}$ (which is homeomorphic to $S^{2m-1}$) as a strong deformation retract via
$A_t(x_1,\dots,x_m,x_{m+1},\dots) = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m,(1-t)x_{m+1},(1-t)x_{m+2},\dots)$ for $t\in[0,1]$, thus the homotopy group $\pi_{2m-1}(S) = \mathbb Z$.

$S(0,1)$, however, has $\pi_{2m-1}(S(0,1)) = 0$ since it is contractible: shift first all coordinates one step to the right and then contract in the stereographic chart opposite $(1,0,0,\dots)$.
Or use the contraction described on page 513 of [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf).

Comment: I feel that you should modify your deformation formula so that it would indeed work (a minor thing).

Comment: It is true that $S$ is homeomorphic to $S_m\times \ell^2$ with
$$S_m:=\{y\in \mathbb{C}^m; \|y\|=1\}?$$

Comment: @Schüler: yes, it is: $$S\ni (x_1,\dots)\mapsto (x_1,2x_2,\dots,mx_m,x_{m+1},\dots)\in S_m \times \ell^2;$$ Note $S_m = S^{2m-1}$.

Comment: @PeterMichor I think that $S_m\times \ell^2$ cannot be homeomorphic to the $1$-shere of $\ell^2$. And thus  $S$ is not homeomorphic to the $1$-shere of $\ell^2$. Do you agree with me? Thanks

Comment: @Schüler: Yes,  a proof of that is the content of my answer.

Comment: @PeterMichor Please why $S_m \times l^2$ is not contractible?: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space

Comment: @Schüler: Because $S_m$ is not contractible, and it sits in $S_m\times \ell^2$ as a strong deformation retract.